# Currency needed for stop over at Kuala Lumpur airport

Tags: money, malaysia

We have a short stop over at Kuala Lumpur airport and would like to know what currency can be used in shops there please.

Comment: VISA, MasterCard, American Express, etc...  They probably also take US dollars, euros, pounds, yen, etc., but the exchange rate will be rather unfavorable.

Answer (score 5):

You can use USD, but may receive change in MYR.  You could also take out money at an ATM.

Depending on your bank fees, you might be better off using a Visa or MasterCard.